# Calculate average clustering of degree k

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

How I can calclulate the average clustering c(k) of nodes of degree k of a graph using NetworkX library in Python?
The only function I can find is for the nodes (some or all of them) and another one for the whole graph.

Comment: I would take the function that can be called for some of the nodes and give it the nodes of degree k.  Then find the average.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all nodes of degree k and then get the average clustering degree

Example:

```
>>> G=nx.complete_graph(5)
>>> k=4
>>> nodes_degree_k = [u for u in G.nodes() if G.degree(u) == k]
>>> clustering_coeff = nx.clustering(G, nodes_degree_k)
>>> sum(clustering_coeff.values())/len(clustering_coeff)
1.0
```

It can be extended to every degree by just grouping nodes.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for u in G.nodes():
   d[G.degree(u)].append(u)

for degree in d:
   clustering_coeff = nx.clustering(G, d[degree])
   print(degree, sum(clustering_coeff.values())/len(clustering_coeff))
```

Comment: thanks, but this is for every degree and after i have to plot on log log scale (x axis= degree k and y axis average clustering for each degree

Comment: What do you mean? You didn't ask for the average clustering coefficient of all the nodes with a specific degree?

Comment: `for degree in sorted(d)`: